# Jupyter doesn't appear in pip packages list

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I installed `jupyter` package as follows:

```
jscherman@lenovo-x1c:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ pip install jupyter
Collecting jupyter
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/df/0f5dd132200728a86190397e1ea87cd76244e42d39ec5e88efd25b2abd7e/jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/ea/280d6c0d92f8e3ca15fd798bbcc2ea141489f9539de7133d8fe10ea4b049/nbconvert-5.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (387kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 389kB 3.4MB/s 
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/24/fabc09ad81c6071159a4d12d5bfbddcbea69bd9e3b16c3250ef300c0285f/ipywidgets-7.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (106kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 776kB/s 
Collecting notebook (from jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/1f/e113875e6b8c8ee0e8c5748bf6fc942a109874adc9ca25248e95cf069803/notebook-5.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.0MB)
    1% |▋                               | 153kB 912kB/s eta 0:00:09^C
Operation cancelled by user
jscherman@lenovo-x1c:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ clear
jscherman@lenovo-x1c:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ pip install jupyter
Collecting jupyter
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/df/0f5dd132200728a86190397e1ea87cd76244e42d39ec5e88efd25b2abd7e/jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/ea/280d6c0d92f8e3ca15fd798bbcc2ea141489f9539de7133d8fe10ea4b049/nbconvert-5.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (387kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 389kB 130kB/s 
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/24/fabc09ad81c6071159a4d12d5bfbddcbea69bd9e3b16c3250ef300c0285f/ipywidgets-7.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (106kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 981kB/s 
Collecting notebook (from jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/1f/e113875e6b8c8ee0e8c5748bf6fc942a109874adc9ca25248e95cf069803/notebook-5.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.0MB 480kB/s 
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/ff/047e0dca2627b162866920e7aa93f04523c0ae81e5c67060eec85701992d/qtconsole-4.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 514kB/s 
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/82/6469cd7fccf7958cbe5dce2e623f1e3c5e27f1bb1ad36d90519bc2d5d370/jupyter_console-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipykernel (from jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/65/c7ca3e3d05f9bd51b3010076b84f4e7304b12d0abf62a48f6cec2c90c019/ipykernel-4.8.2-py2-none-any.whl (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 650kB/s 
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
Collecting entrypoints>=0.2.2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/8b/4eefa9b47f1910b3d2081da67726b066e379b04ca897acfe9f92bac56147/entrypoints-0.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (2.8)
Collecting testpath (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/19/d7bc380c479a184e4a5a9ce516e4e2a773165f89b445f7cdced83d94de25/testpath-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (161kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 606kB/s 
Collecting mistune>=0.7.4 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/8c/87f4d359438ba0321a2ae91936030110bfcc62fef752656321a72b8c1af9/mistune-0.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbformat>=4.4 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/27/9a654d2b6cc1eaa517d1c5a4405166c7f6d72f04f6e7eea41855fe808a46/nbformat-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 301kB/s 
Collecting pygments (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/ee/b6e02dc6529e82b75bb06823ff7d005b141037cb1416b10c6f00fc419dca/Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (841kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 849kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting bleach (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/b6/a8cffbb9ab4b62b557c22703163735210e9cd857d533740c64e1467d228e/bleach-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting traitlets>=4.2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/d6/abcb22de61d78e2fc3959c964628a5771e47e7cc60d53e9342e21ed6cc9a/traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 518kB/s 
Collecting jupyter-core (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/44/065d2d7bae7bebc06f1dd70d23c36da8c50c0f08b4236716743d706762a8/jupyter_core-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 906kB/s 
Collecting ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3" (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/af/fbc5ecbb283344365ac98079524f8d61fd1b2afcef31d469023cba80b439/ipython-5.6.0-py2-none-any.whl (760kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 768kB 1.0MB/s 
Collecting widgetsnbextension~=3.2.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/fa/64acc09fc845a6b2dc0724d6f3f81e829b778ed5e9a7559567b4f19a3f4b/widgetsnbextension-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.2MB 2.0MB/s 
Collecting Send2Trash (from notebook->jupyter)
Collecting ipython-genutils (from notebook->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/bc/9bd3b5c2b4774d5f33b2d544f1460be9df7df2fe42f352135381c347c69a/ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-client>=5.2.0 (from notebook->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/dd/fe6c4d683b09eb05342bd2816b7779663f71762b4fa9c2d5203d35d17354/jupyter_client-5.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (89kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 494kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (4.2.1)
Collecting terminado>=0.8.1 (from notebook->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/20/a26211a24425923d46e1213b376a6ee60dc30bcdf1b0c345e2c3769deb1c/terminado-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 (from jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/b0/1a6c262da35c779dd79550137aa7c298a424987240a28792ec5ccf48f848/prompt_toolkit-1.0.15-py2-none-any.whl (247kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 838kB/s 
Collecting configparser>=3.5; python_version == "2.7" (from entrypoints>=0.2.2->nbconvert->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from jinja2->nbconvert->jupyter) (0.23)
Collecting jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 (from nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/de/47e35a97b2b05c2fadbec67d44cfcdcd09b8086951b331d82de90d2912da/jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting html5lib!=1.0b1,!=1.0b2,!=1.0b3,!=1.0b4,!=1.0b5,!=1.0b6,!=1.0b7,!=1.0b8,>=0.99999999pre (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/62/bbd2be0e7943ec8504b517e62bab011b4946e1258842bc159e5dfde15b96/html5lib-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (117kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 782kB/s 
Collecting six (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->nbconvert->jupyter) (4.0.6)
Collecting enum34; python_version == "2.7" (from traitlets>=4.2->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/db/e56e6b4bbac7c4a06de1c50de6fe1ef3810018ae11732a50f15f62c7d050/enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (4.0.1)
Collecting backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/cd/1750d6c35fe86d35f8562091737907f234b78fdffab42b29c72b1dd861f4/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (20.7.0)
Collecting pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/4e/68add57f8b993bb5da70c22c7eebb4266c7b66cab15095a1578cc6a62b1a/pathlib2-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.8.1)
Collecting pickleshare (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/17/daa142fc9be6b76f26f24eeeb9a138940671490b91cb5587393f297c8317/pickleshare-0.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.2.0->notebook->jupyter) (15.2.0)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from jupyter-client>=5.2.0->notebook->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/57/19f3a65bcf6d5be570ee8c35a5398496e10a0ddcbc95393b2d17f86aaaf8/python_dateutil-2.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (212kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 578kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess; os_name != "nt" in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from terminado>=0.8.1->notebook->jupyter) (0.5)
Collecting wcwidth (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/9f/526a6947247599b084ee5232e4f9190a38f398d7300d866af3ab571a5bfe/wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting functools32; python_version == "2.7" (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->jupyter)
Collecting webencodings (from html5lib!=1.0b1,!=1.0b2,!=1.0b3,!=1.0b4,!=1.0b5,!=1.0b6,!=1.0b7,!=1.0b8,>=0.99999999pre->bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/24/2a3e3df732393fed8b3ebf2ec078f05546de641fe1b667ee316ec1dcf3b7/webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scandir; python_version < "3.5" (from pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3"->ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter)
Installing collected packages: pandocfilters, configparser, entrypoints, testpath, mistune, ipython-genutils, six, enum34, traitlets, jupyter-core, functools32, jsonschema, nbformat, pygments, webencodings, html5lib, bleach, nbconvert, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, backports.shutil-get-terminal-size, scandir, pathlib2, pickleshare, ipython, Send2Trash, python-dateutil, jupyter-client, terminado, ipykernel, notebook, widgetsnbextension, ipywidgets, qtconsole, jupyter-console, jupyter
```

Then, when i try running it, i get

```
jscherman@lenovo-x1c:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ jupyter notebook
jupyter: command not found
```

Let's see why:

```
jscherman@lenovo-x1c:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -------
adium-theme-ubuntu 0.3.4  
decorator          4.0.6  
ipython            2.4.1  
Jinja2             2.8    
MarkupSafe         0.23   
meld               3.14.2 
pexpect            4.0.1  
pip                10.0.0 
ptyprocess         0.5    
pycurl             7.43.0 
pygobject          3.20.0 
PyMySQL            0.7.2  
pyzmq              15.2.0 
setuptools         20.7.0 
simplegeneric      0.8.1  
tornado            4.2.1  
unity-lens-photos  1.0    
wheel              0.29.0
```

Why doesn't it appear in the list? A little context:

```
jscherman@lenovo-x1c:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
jscherman@lenovo-x1c:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ pip --version
pip 10.0.0 from /home/jscherman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Any idea what's going on? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try this: python -m pip install jupyter

Comment: @KshitijNikhal already done that. Nothing changes

Comment: Could you check if jupyter is installed in /home/jscherman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages ?
It seems like pip is not installing site packages in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Try uninstalling pip 
sudo apt remove python-pip

and installing it this way
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py